# Using R Shiny with plotly to make a scatterplot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am brand new to Rshiny and trying to figure out why the code I have is not giving me a plotly graph. I have a file called 'final' (tbl_df) that contains all the columns that I using. I am trying to have a scatterplot where both x and y axis's have the same list (in a dropdown) and trying to see how these values change by week.

When I Run the app, I get a blank graph, but I can click on my three dropdowns (choose a week, x-axis, & y-axis). But when I click on different values of my dropdowns, nothing happens but the x and y axis labels change.

Here's what it looks like:
[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrzj2.png)

I am wondering if I have to use reactive with my x and y values as well as 'Week' for this to work? I am concerned if scaling could be a reason why I'm having trouble as well.

Here's what I have..

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Weekly updates"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
           selectInput(inputID = "Week", label= "Choose a week:", choices =unique(final$Week), selected ="44"),

           selectInput(inputId = "y", label = "y-axis", 
                       choices =c("Height","Weight","Color", "Shape"), 
                       selected = "Height"),
     
           selectInput(inputId = "x", label = "x-axis", 
                       choices =c("Height", "Weight", "Color", "Shape")
                       selected = "Weight")
),

      mainPanel(
         plotlyOutput(outputId = "scatter")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$scatter <-renderPlotly({

         plot_ly(data=final) %>%
       add_trace(x=~input$x, y=~input$y,
                 type= 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
                 text = final$Sample,
                 hoverinfo = 'text'
                 showlegend = F)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input$x` and `input$y` return characters, so this resolves to something like `add_trace(x=~"Height", y=~"Weight",...` instead of `add_trace(x=~Height, y=~Weight,...`.

You can however turn this into a formula instead

```
       plot_ly(data=final) %>%
       add_trace(x = as.formula(paste0("~",input$x)),
                 y = as.formula(paste0("~",input$y)),
                 type= 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
                 text = final$Sample,
                 hoverinfo = 'text'
                 showlegend = F)
```

Comment: @m.rodwell this is at least part of the issue - to reproduce/solve the problem it is usally helpful if you can provide some of the data, e.g. by adding the output of `dput(head(final))` in your question

Comment: When I utilize the formula, it only graphs the values that are set equal to selected, in this case height & weight and gives an unexpected symbol error when I try to graph the others.

Comment: Does it work for any initially selected input values? Then the plotly part (and column names) should be fine, but there may be issues with updates to reactive values. I've made a toy example where this works smoothly including changes to the input values. These are essentially the things that are much easier to check with a reproducible example (minimal functioning code + data).

Comment: Would there be a way to set parameters for each separate x&y value. Such as Height 0-100mm and weight 0-200mm?

Comment: you can probably make a list of axis ranges for each variable, then pick the relevant ones based on the input and pass it to the plot. Not sure how to integrate it with `plot_ly` (I assume it's possible), but you could also do the same plot using [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/), set the ranges via `coord_cartesian` and wrap the output in `ggplotly` (also from the plotly package).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This was the only part of my code that needed to be changed... Thank you for your help!

```
server <- function(input, output) {

output$scatter <- renderPlotly ({
   plot_ly(data=filter(final, Week == input$Week)) %>%
      add_trace(
        x= as.formula(paste0("~`", input$x, "`")),
        y= as.formula(paste0("~`", input$y, "`")),
        type = 'scatter'
        mode = 'markers'
        text = filter(final, Week == input$Week)$Sample,
        hoverinfo = 'text'
        showlegend = F)
   })
}
```